# WordPress get_posts por fecha

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Quiero hacer una consulta en WordPress y obtener los 6 posts siguiente con mayor fecha del posts actual.
Utilizo get_posts de esta manera y con estos argumentos:

```
$args = [
            'order' => 'ASC', 
            'orderby'=>'date',
            'numberposts' => 6,
            'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID()),
             'date_query' => array(
                array( 'column'  => 'post_date','after' => get_the_date() ) 
            ), 
            
        ];
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Esta consulta la hago desde el hook **the_conten**t y mi problema es que que si es el post mas antiguo si me da los tres siguientes por fecha pero en los demás me devuelve también anteriores al actual por fecha.

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Hola. En `date_query` te falta especificar a qué columna debe aplicarse el criterio. Prueba a ponerlo así: **`'date_query' => array( 'column'  => 'post_date', 'after' => get_the_date() )`**

Comment: Si no funciona así, considera poner el criterio `after` dentro de otro array, algo así: **`'date_query' => array( array( 'after' => get_the_date() ) )`**

Comment: He modificado los argumentos según las sugerencias de -A. Cedano pero sigue dándome post siguientes y anteriores en fecha.
Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: El problema podría ser el formato de la fecha que te arroja `get_the_date()` por defecto, el cual no haría coincidir las fechas. Intenta así: **`$args = [
            'order' => 'ASC', 
            'numberposts' => 3,
            'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID()),
            'date_query' => array(
                'after' => get_the_date('Y-m-d') 
            ) 
            
        ];
$posts = get_posts($args);`**

Comment: Waooo! gracias A. Cedano este era el problema y ya esta solucionado. Ahora me surge otro y es que en los últimos 3 post con la fecha mas actual  ya no retorna 3 posts porque no hay fechas "after". ¿Cómo podría hacerlo para que empiece otra vez por las mas antiguas?

Comment: En ese caso deberías cambiar el `after` por `before`.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `get_the_date()` no te devuelve un formato de fecha adecuado para hacer la comparación.

Deberías especificar un formato que sirva para comparar la fecha de los posts en la tabla de Wordpress, por ejemplo: `Y-m-d`.

Para los posts posteriores, el código sería así:

```
$args = [             
         'order' => 'ASC', 
         'numberposts' => 3, 
         'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID()), 
         'date_query' => [
                          'after' => get_the_date('Y-m-d')
                         ]
        ];
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Y para los posts anteriores, el código sería así:

```
$args = [             
         'order' => 'ASC', 
         'numberposts' => 3, 
         'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID()), 
         'date_query' => [
                          'before' => get_the_date('Y-m-d')
                         ]
        ];
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: No es eso lo que necesitaba. el tema es que obtenga los 3 posts siguiente por fecha, pero cuando es el penúltimo posts por fecha por ejemplo , solo retorna 1 porque solo hay 1 mas nuevo. Lo que quiero conseguir es que si no puede dar tres mas nuevos empiece por los viejos. en este caso ser 1 mas nuevo y los dos primero mas antiguos

Comment: @J.rafaelsimarro ese es un nuevo problema y debería ser tratado en una nueva pregunta en caso de que no logres resolverlo. Sería relativamente fácil, basándose en este mismo código podrías verificar el número de posts y si es menor a tres buscar entonces los más viejos con una nueva consulta.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano , si hare una nueva pregunta, y referente a tu solución ya lo había valorado pero hacer dos consultas para una misma vista no me parecía optimo , pero lo hare en caso que no encuentre otra solución.

Comment: @J.rafaelsimarro realmente lo que ocurre tras bastidores es una consulta SQL. Tú podrías entonces armar una sola consulta que te traiga los posteriores y si no hay más de tres que te traiga los anteriores. Ignoro si esto es posible mediante los argumentos de WordPress. En una nueva pregunta podrás exponer con amplitud lo que hayas investigado, el código escrito y los eventuales problemas o errores.